# Read output model of plink

Tags: python, pandas, csv, genetics

### Task

I need to work with the software plink to do an association study. After inputting all the data and doing all calculations I get a file/ table that looks like this:

```
CHR SNP                           A1 A2 TEST  AFF     UNAFF   CHISQ     DF P
1   rs10458597                    T  C  TREND 4/230   13/973  0.1565    1  0.6924
1   rs2185539                     T  C  TREND 7/231   0/1000  29.75     1  4.92e-08
1   rs11240767                    T  C  TREND 10/228  15/985  6.206     1  0.01273
1   rs12564807                    G  A  TREND 0/238   0/1000  NA        NA NA
1   rs3131972                     A  G  TREND 82/156  259/741 6.618     1  0.0101
1   rs3131969                     A  G  TREND 86/150  253/733 9.629     1  0.001916
1   rs3131967                     T  C  TREND 73/157  212/768 9.407     1  0.002162
1   rs1048488                     C  T  TREND 60/178  203/791 2.435     1  0.1187
1   rs12562034                    A  G  TREND 60/172  256/734 1.008e-06 1  0.9992
```

I'm only interested in the p-values (last column) and need to generate a Q-Q-Plot. To achieve this I wanted to read in the file with pandas, but I can not find a way to properly read the file.

### Previous Attempts

I tried using Excel to interpret the file and generate a proper `.csv` but since the file is too big, Excel always fails to do so and crashes/ generates only a third of the table.

I have also tried to use the following commands to read the file with pandas, but I get the wrong output:

#### Commands

```py
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t', engine='python')  # attempt 1
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t', lineterminator='\r')  # attempt 2
```

#### Output:

[image: Output structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with [pd.read_fwf()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html):

```
df = pd.read_fwf(r'c:\test\test_file.txt')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   CHR         SNP A1 A2   TEST     AFF    UNAFF      CHISQ   DF             P
0    1  rs10458597  T  C  TREND   4/230   13/973   0.156500  1.0  6.924000e-01
1    1   rs2185539  T  C  TREND   7/231   0/1000  29.750000  1.0  4.920000e-08
2    1  rs11240767  T  C  TREND  10/228   15/985   6.206000  1.0  1.273000e-02
3    1  rs12564807  G  A  TREND   0/238   0/1000        NaN  NaN           NaN
4    1   rs3131972  A  G  TREND  82/156  259/741   6.618000  1.0  1.010000e-02
5    1   rs3131969  A  G  TREND  86/150  253/733   9.629000  1.0  1.916000e-03
6    1   rs3131967  T  C  TREND  73/157  212/768   9.407000  1.0  2.162000e-03
7    1   rs1048488  C  T  TREND  60/178  203/791   2.435000  1.0  1.187000e-01
8    1  rs12562034  A  G  TREND  60/172  256/734   0.000001  1.0  9.992000e-01
```